# Sumproduct by Category, sum each day and sum top time

Tags: excel, sumproduct

If I have the following data in excel is it possible to get the sum of all the data based upon the data in the table below

[image]

So basically ignore the white rows where the data has been superseded by a later date time ( I've split the date time field in the example).

[image]

I've tried the following formula but I just get #VALUE! errors

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((Table!A:A='Cumulative Baselines'!A27)*(Table!D:D),{1}))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use SUMIF function, check this link for reference https://www.contextures.com/xlfunctions01.html#sumifs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use a SUMIFS, but only in combination with a sum or sumproduct as far as I know:

```
=SUM(D$2:D$20*(A$2:A$20=F2)*(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$20,A$2:A$20,B$2:B$20,B$2:B$20,C$2:C$20,">"&C$2:C$20)=0))
```

(I have used an arbitrary range as it would likely be slow if whole-column ranges were used)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't using the function you're discussing but here is a workable solution if this is time sensitive:

Column E, Row 1:

=COUNTIFS(B1:B11,B1,A1:A11,A1), extend down as needed.

- This is looking at your data sequentially and adding a counter to the row it's on that represents rows with the value in column A and the value in column B matching to row this cell is on. Because your data is ordered oldest to newest, the last instance of that combination will always have a value of 1.

Now we can expand that to:

=IF(COUNTIFS(B1:B11,B1,A1:A11,A1)=1,1,0)

- All values that are not 1 are now 0.  This gives us the criteria needed to use a sumifs statement.

Create a cell with target values to check against:
In my example I have ABC in cell G1 and DEF in G2
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,G1,E:E,1) - extend down as needed

- This conditional sum statement adds up everything in column D that also shares a 1 value in column E and the same value in column A as you placed in G1.

That's the quick and dirty, but sub-optimal in terms of resource utilization (it looks like you're using table column references already instead of entire columns, that's the more efficient way to do it, I didn't have column headers readily available).

Edit: It looks like the key issue here is that max() doesn't play well with custom datetime formats, which is what Excel is natively going to read the unsplit timestamp as and sumproduct reads all non-numeric values as 0. You can massage it to use max by adding a column(again) and bringing in the date and time together as =datevalue(date column cell)+timevalue(time column cell). That will store as a float that max() can be applied to.

The issue with THAT is we still need a column to test if the combined value represents the unique day and then find the recombined timestamp max value for that day, so it's back to the above solution and additional work to enable using sumproduct(). In my experience, the juice won't be worth the squeeze to bootstrap sumproduct() into working in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for this - its helpful,  the reason why I went down the sumproduct route was the data may not always be sequential with the largest values last, so if any previous data is added out of order am I correct in thinking this will show up as the selected row unless it's manually sorted by date time?

Comment: Correct, if the data is non-sequential the date filter breaks down and the whole house of cards falls. I'm assuming based on the datetime stamps that this is going to be coming from an external system, is it possible to have the data sorted at the source? If so, the sheet could be externally referenced to a source and it would literally update itself every time the exref was refreshed.